# how to use Q to search fields in list in django DRF without using querysets

Tags: django, python-3.x, search, django-rest-framework, filtering

```
def list(self, request):
    """"

    """
    query = [Q(role_id=USER_ROLE['employer'])]
    first_name = [Q(request.GET.get('first_name')), Q.AND]
    last_name = [Q(request.GET.get('last_name')), Q.AND]
    if first_name:
        query = query.filter(first_name=first_name)
    if last_name:
        query = query.filter(last_name=last_name)

    user_obj = User.objects.filter(query)
    serializer_data = self.serializer_class(user_obj, many=True).data
    return custom_response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, detail=SUCCESS_CODE['3007'], data=serializer_data)
```

In this i am getting the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the logic that filters on `employer` and if reaquest has `first_name` filter by it and if it has `last_name`. So it work as well if here is both `first_name` and `last_name.

```
query = Q(role_id=USER_ROLE['employer'])
first_name = request.GET.get('first_name')
last_name = request.GET.get('last_name')
if first_name:
    query =& Q(first_name=first_name)
if last_name:
    query =& Q(last_name=last_name))

user_obj = User.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Please update your question with new applied logic that I suggested @RobinChauhan

Answer (score 0):

Currently what i'm understanding from your query is that if there a `first_name` request value then you search user with role_id = USER_ROLE['employer'] and first_name= first_name, if there last name request then it's the same except only filter by last_name.

Which doesn't need an OR condition in query:

```
first_name = request.GET.get('first_name')
last_name = request.GET.get('last_name')

if first_name:
   user_obj = User.objects.filter(role_id=USER_ROLE['employer'], first_name=first_name)
if last_name:
   user_obj = User.objects.filter(role_id=USER_ROLE['employer'], last_name=last_name)
```

correct me if i'm wrong